# How do I efficiently evaluate a convolution integral between different-sized domains?

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

This is a question that I've previously asked over on math.stackexchange, and I have yet to receive a useful answer. It was suggested that I post this here.

The problem itself originally comes from simulation of wave propagation, and involves large two-dimensional arrays of complex data. I'll explain it here as a simplified one-dimensional problem, however.

Suppose I have the following integral relationship involving a convolution:
$$
f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx'\, g(x')\, K(x - x')
$$
Assume that the functional form of the kernel $K$ is known, and suppose that the function $g$ has compact support on $[-a/2, +a/2]$ for some width $a>0$. Assume further that I have data about the function $g$ in the form of $N$ equally-spaced samples $g_n$:
$$
g_n = g(x_n)\, ,
$$ 
where 
$$
x_n = -\frac{a}{2} + n\frac{a}{N}\, , \qquad n = 0,..., N-1
$$
My goal is to generate some $N$ evenly-spaced samples of the function $f$.

If we suppose that we want to evaluate $f$ on the *same domain* on which $g$ lives, and for which we have samples of $g$, then it's easy. I discretize everything in the usual way, and the whole thing becomes a discrete convolution:
$$
f_n = f(x_n) = \sum_{m = 0}^{N-1} g_m K_{n - m}\, ,
$$
where
$$
K_{n - m} = K(x_n - x_m) = K\left(\frac{a}{N}(n-m)\right)\, .
$$
Everything is simple since I can use the [discrete convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Functions_of_discrete_variable_sequences): I FFT the $\{g_n\}$ and $\{K_n\}$ sequences, multiply them, do an inverse FFT, and I'm done. I have my $\{f_n\}$ data. The whole thing will be an $O(N\log N)$ process.

Suppose instead that I have to evaluate $f$ on a different-sized domain. For example, perhaps the $g$ data is narrow, but the kernel $K$ is very wide. Let's say I have to generate $N$ samples of $f$ on the domain $[-L/2, +L/2]$, for some domain width $L > a$. $L$ could even be *much* larger than *a*.

If I try to discretize everything in a similar way, I'd have to first define a sequence of points $\{X_n\}$ in the wider domain:
$$
X_n = -\frac{L}{2} + n\frac{L}{N}\, , \qquad n = 0,..., N-1
$$
Then the data I seek is $\{f_n\}$ where $f_n = f(X_n)$. The original integral is still over the smaller domain, so we have:
\begin{align}
f_n
&= \int_{-a/2}^{+a/2}dx'\, g(x')\, K(X_n - x') \\
&\approx \sum_{m = 0}^{N-1} g_m\, K(X_n - x_m) \qquad \text{(discretize)}\\
&= \sum_{m = 0}^{N-1} g_m\, K\left(\frac{L-a}{2} + \frac{a}{N}(\alpha\, n - m)\right)\, ,
\end{align}
where $\alpha = L/a > 1$ is the ratio of the two domain sizes.

This is no longer a discrete convolution, since the second term is no longer a function of $n-m$, but instead of $\alpha\, n - m$. So I can no longer use the convolution theorem. I can imagine evaluating the sum above by brute force, but that would be an $O(N^2)$ process, which is prohibitive for my problem.

Is there any way of **efficiently** calculating the discrete version of this convolution integral between two different domain sizes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, to my understanding this problems boils down to a fast-convolution problem:

You have a function $g(x)$, which has a small domain and you have a function $K(\tau)$, which has a big domain and you want to calculate

$$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x')K(x-x')dx'$$

in a discretized fashion, where you want to calculate as efficient as possible. Especially, you are interested in $f(-L/2+nL/N)$ for $n=0,\dots,N-1$.

When considering the discretization you need to take care of the bandwidth of $g$ and $K$ and you need to sample with the according Nyquist frequency at least. Let's assume that $g$ can be sufficiently sampled with $g(-\frac{a}{2}+n\frac{a}{N})$ (i.e. the sampling is fast enough regarding Nyquist frequency). Let's also assume, that $K(\tau)$ has the same or smaller bandwith, i.e. the sampling rate for $g$ is also sufficient for $K$.

Then, let's further assume $L=qa, q\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. L is a multiple of $a$. Define the following functions:

$$g[n]=g(-\frac{L}{2}+n\frac{L}{qN}), \quad n=0,\dots,qN-1$$
and
$$K[n]=K(-\frac{L}{2}+n\frac{L}{qN}), \quad n=0,\dots,qN-1$$

Note, that $g[n]$ is zero for most $n$, but that is fine here.

Now, you have

$$f[n]=\sum_n'g[n']*K[n-n'], \quad n=0,\dots,qN-1$$

Which is a higher-resolution version of your original $f_n$ (It has qN instead of only N samples within the interval $\pm\frac{L}{2}$). So, what you actually want to have is a downsampled version of this $f[n]$ given by

$f_n=f[qn]$ (where $f_n$ is the $f_n$ from your post, i.e. with $n=0,\dots,N-1$.

So, this is also a discrete convolution problem, and it can be solved via FFT (note that the FFT actually considers circular convolution, if you don't zero-pad). However, since your $g[n]$ has a much smaller domain that $K[n]$, you can resort to fast-convolution algorithms ([Overlap-save](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method) or [Overlap-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method)).

To summarize: The trick is actually just to sample both signals with the same sampling frequency (accepting that $g[n]$ contains a lot of zeros) and then understanding this problem as a simple discrete convolution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't just sample my kernel $K$ with finer sampling frequency, it would generate too much data to handle. My original problem is 2D, with an array of complex numbers about 1000 x 1000 in size. For my problem, $L/a = q = \alpha \sim 100$, which means that the over-sampled $K$ would contain about $10^{10}$ complex numbers.

Comment: OK, I see, it's a memory problem. This would have been an important message in the question. Then, can you sample $g$ with the frequency you want to sample $K$ (i.e. is the bandwidth of $g$ small enough for that)? This would easily solve your problem. If not, you can low-pass filter $g$ and then do the sampling with the frequency you want for $K$. You can do this, assuming that there is no aliasing in sampling $K$ (i.e. after convolution, the higher parts of $g$ would be gone anyway since $K$ is much narrower in frequency domain)

Comment: Unfortunately, $g$ is already sampled at the appropriate sampling frequency for that function. I can't low-pass filter it without loosing too much information. My motivation behind this question is the fact that I can calculate the convolution in only a second or two when the domains are the same size ($L = a$). Changing the size of the final domain appears to leave only the brute force approach, which takes one or two *days*. I was amazed that that one change could make such a drastic difference, and I hoped there would be some way of doing it faster which would be well-known to dsp people.

Comment: Consider $g$ is of bandwidth $B_g$ and $K$ is of bandwidth $B_K$ with $B_K<B_g$. Then, the convolution of both signals (in continuous time) would have bandwidth $min(B_K,B_g)=B_K$, since both spectra are multiplied in frequency domain. So, I think you can low-pass filter $g$ before the convolution to the bandwidth of $K$, and then you can apply the lower sampling rate.