# Convolution of $(3/4)^nu(n-2)$ and $2^nu(-n-5)$

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

I am trying to convolve the two discrete sequences

$$\left(\frac34\right)^nu(n-2)$$

and $$2^nu(-n-5)$$

where $u(n)$ is the unit step function.

Here is how I approached the problem ,using the convolution sum

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x(k)h(n-k)$$

in this case ,

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac34\right)^ku(k-2)2^{n-k}u(-(n-k)-5)$$

which becomes

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac34\right)^ku(k-2)\frac{2^n}{2^k}u(-n+k-5)$$

now $u(k-2)$ in non zero when $k \ge 2$ and $u(-n+k-5)$ in non zero when $k \ge n+5$ ***(this is exactly where I am confused on how to set the limits of k based on the second condition)***

if I use $k \ge 2$ for the sum , then the sum becomes

$$2^n\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac38\right)^k$$

using GP sum , it comes out to

$$2^n\left(\frac85 - 1-\frac38 \right)= 2^n\frac{9}{40}$$

But the solution given in the book by the author is

$$y(n) = \frac{1}{20}\left(\frac34\right)^{n+5}u(n+2)+\frac{9}{40}2^nu(-n-3)$$

This solution doesn't even remotely resemble mine.

Comment: Please edit your question with Latex formatting. As is, it’s pretty unreadable. You can use [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/37198/63763) as an example. Click “edit” on the question linked, and you’ll see how to nicely format things!

Comment: I am new to Latex formatting , if someone can help me with formatting this question , would be grateful , especially with symbols like sigma , upper and lower ,limits of sums ..,exponents ..etc.- Thanks.

Comment: I managed to format the question reasonably , hope its ok now - Thanks.

Comment: corrected the same now , hope this is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first steps are correct, but then you need to distinguish two cases. Note that both conditions $k\ge 2$ and $k\ge n+5$ must be satisfied for the sum to be non-zero:

$$y[n]=2^n\sum_{k=\max\{2,n+5\}}^{\infty}\left(\frac38\right)^k$$

For $n\le -3$ we have the lower index $k=2$, and your result is correct. However, for $n\ge -2$ the lower limit becomes $k=n+5$, which will give you the other term mentioned in the book's solution. For the final result, you need to combine both terms, multiplied with appropriately shifted step sequences.